# How can I get this python panel I wrote to pipe correctly to dzen?

Tags: python, linux, bash, panel, window-managers

I'm trying to pipe the output of the following script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import string
import os

status_cmd = 'herbstclient tag_status'
idle_cmd = 'herbstclient --idle'

def parse_tags(output):
    #Takes herbstclient tag_status and parses it
    #returns a nested list of tags.
    tags = output.split()
    taglist = ''
    for i in range(len(tags)):
        if tags[i][0] == '#':
            s = '^bg(' + colors[3] + ')' + tags[i][1:] + ' '
            taglist += s
        elif tags[i][0] == ':':
            taglist += '^bg(' + colors[4] + ')' + tags[i][1:] + ' '
    return taglist

def parse_xdef():
#Returns the colors in Xresources in a list
#in the order they appear in Xresources
    os.chdir('/home/damian/')
    fin = open('.Xresources')
    colors = []
    for line in fin:
        color = line.strip()
        if 'color' in color:
            rgb = color[color.find('#'):]
            colors.append(rgb)
        elif 'background' in color:
            colors.append(color[color.find('#'):])
        elif 'foreground' in color:
            colors.append(color[color.find('#'):])
    return(colors)

colors = parse_xdef()
single_line_out = ''
idlein = os.popen(idle_cmd)
#for line in idlein:

for line in idlein.readline()
    if 'tag' in line:
        proc = os.popen(status_cmd)
        output = proc.readline()
        taglist = parse_tags(output)
        single_line_out = taglist
        print(single_line_out)
```

Through dzen or bar but it doesn't work. it is a script to show and update the tags from herbstcluent and It works on its own in the terminal: whenever I change tabs it prints the tablist formated for dzen but whenever I try to pipe it to a bar the bar stays black. Please do help.

Comment: Is the problem that the output isn't working or that the colors aren't working? If you `tee` the output to a file does it look correct when used in the `dzen` pipeline? Is this a buffering issue?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by tee'ing the output. And how would I pipe that to dzen? through a 'cat file | dzen2 -p' ??
The problem is dzen and bar are showing an empty bar but the output is the expected output when the script is ran on the commandline. When ran in the commandline the output is something along the lines of:
^bg(#B91E2E)1 ^bg(#606060)2

Comment: You said pipe. I assumed that meant something like that, yes. I don't use dzen. If that isn't how it works then that isn't a reasonable way to test things.

Comment: How are you using this with dzen currently? Is `bar` part of dzen or something else?

Comment: I'm testing it with: 
"./panel_dzen.py | dzen2 -p -w 400"
which does work correctly with, say:
"echo 'hello world' | dzen2 -p -w 400".
Bar is just an alternative to dzen.

Comment: Ok, then yes, I would try `./panel_dzen.py | tee /tmp/panel_dzen.out | dzen2 -p -w 400` and make sure the contents of the file look correct (and appear in reasonable time (check with `tail -f` on that file). I'd also try using `unbuffer` or `stdbuf` if you have them.

Comment: The tail -f /tmp/panel_dzen.out returns nothing. I might have to try managing the piping through python.

Comment: Does it ever get anything? It should eventually but might take a while if the output data is not large (and the script is looping).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be getting anything. The "./panel_dzen.py | tee /tmp/panel_dzen.out | dzen2 -p -w 400" is running at the same time as the "tail -f /tmp/panel_dzen.out "and it doesn't output anythign.

Comment: Does your script loop or just output once? If you tell the script not to loop do you get output when it is done?

Comment: If I don't loop my script it prints once to /tmp/dzen_panel.out but it doesn't display anything on dzen.

Comment: Try the `unbuffer` or `stdbuf` commands if you have them. Otherwise try forcing unbuffered output from the script.

Comment: I will try them. I have stdbuf. How should I add them to my piping scheme?

Comment: `stdbuf ./panel_dzen.py | tee /tmp/panel_dzen.out | dzen2 -p -w 400` I think. Try without the `tee` bit if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here late, I believe the solution is to flush the output.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```